# Display Number of Accounts Called in Quarter using Dashboard Component

Tags: reporting, dashboard, activities

I am currently using Professional Edition. I need to create a Dashboard Component that displays the number of Accounts called by a user in current quarter. For example, Joe owns 65 Accounts and has called 40 Accounts this quarter. I would like a visual way of representing this

I have created a report that contains Accounts with Activities but this only counts the Activities, and not the Accounts.

Any ideas on how to go about the above? (I am open to using any Dashboard Component Types)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to group by date field on Account (Quarter) , which looks like below image.

[image: Sample Chart]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to see Last Activity Date (last called) in the past quarter, along with ALL of the other accounts that are owned by me. So I'm afraid the above does not meet my requirement.